# .NET MAUI how to access ContentView property in CollectionView DataTemplate

Tags: c#, maui

I have a component that has a property:

```
private bool canSelectCheckBox = true;

public bool CanSelectCheckBox
{
    get
    {
        return canSelectCheckBox;
    }
}
```

In my XAML I need to set a checkbox to be visible or not depending on this property, but I can't figure it out how. I know how to do it when I have a view model, but now I need a property form the code behind.

```
<CollectionView ItemsSource="{Binding Images, Source={x:Reference this}}" MinimumHeightRequest="0">
    <CollectionView.ItemsLayout>
        <GridItemsLayout Orientation="Vertical" 
                Span="{OnIdiom Default=3}"
                HorizontalItemSpacing="10" VerticalItemSpacing="10"/>
    </CollectionView.ItemsLayout>
    <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate x:DataType="models:ImageModel">
            <Frame Style="{StaticResource ImageControlImageFrameWrapper}" Padding="0">
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.Resources>
                        <Style TargetType="ImageButton">
                            <Setter Property="VerticalOptions" Value="FillAndExpand" />
                            <Setter Property="HorizontalOptions" Value="FillAndExpand" />
                            <Setter Property="Aspect" Value="AspectFill" />
                            <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="Transparent" />
                        </Style>
                    </Grid.Resources>

                    <ImageButton Source="{Binding FilePath}" Clicked="OnPopupOpen" />

                    <CheckBox Style="{StaticResource ImageControlCheckbox}"
                              CheckedChanged="OnCheckBoxCheckedChanged" 
                              IsVisible="{Binding Source={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ImageControl}}, Path=CanSelectCheckBox}"/>
                </Grid>
            </Frame>
        </DataTemplate>
    </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
</CollectionView>
```

thnx

Comment: where is the `ImageControl` in your XAML?

Comment: The ImageControl is the whole component

Comment: try `{Binding Source={x:Reference page}, Path= CanSelectCheckBox}` and add `x:Name="page"` to the `ContentView`.  And `CanSelectCheckBox` needs to be `Observable` for this to update the UI dynamically

Comment: Already tried IsVisible="{Binding Source={x:Reference this}, Path=CanSelectCheckBox}" where the name of the ContentView is set as "this"

Comment: what is the actual problem?  Is the property getter being called?  There is no setter so how can this ever be updated?

Comment: I do not understand, now it is working!